# Handle null username in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, null

I have a review section in my app which uses the user's username as the heading along with their review. Everything works well unless the user does not have a username set up yet. I am trying to create a condition where if the user does not have a username set, it will be Anonymous.

I am using Redux to add the reviews.

Here is my code where I dispatch my action along with the username, uid, and review to the action creator:

```
const review = this.props.review.review;
//const username = this.props.userData.username.username;
const uid = this.props.string.uid;

const username = () => {
   if (!this.props.userData.username.username) {
         return 'Anonymous';
    }
          return this.props.userData.username.username;
    };

 //dispatch action with my values
 this.props.submitUserReview({ review, username, uid });
```

I appreciate any help and guidance with this issue. Cheers!

SOLVED:

I solved this by using lodash thanks to Noah Allen:

const username = _.get(userData, 'username.username', 'Anonymous')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Lodash one-liner:

```
const username = _.get(userData, 'username.username', 'Anonymous')
```

To fix your example, you really only need to add a pair of parenthesis (explanation below):

```
 this.props.submitUserReview({ review, username: username(), uid });
```

Taking it a step further you should do this to help improve code readability, re-use, and abstraction:

```
function checkUsername (userData) {
  // Checks for undefined, null, and a string with no characters:
  if (userData && userData.username && userData.username.username && username.length > 0) {
    return userData.username.username
  }
  // Default case:
  return 'Anonymous'
}
```

Then in your component:

```
 this.props.submitUserReview({ review, username: checkUsername(this.props.userData), uid })
```

Basically you were passing the function username to your submission, rather than running the function and passing the result of the function to submission. In this example, you define the check username function elsewhere to help with abstraction. And then in your submission you run the function and pass the result of it to your `submitUserReview` function.

Note that in JS, when you have a function:`const x = () => 1`, the type of x will be a function. As soon as you use the parenthesis, the function gets called: `x()`, and the value is returned. So in your original example, you were passing `x` as a parameter - which means that it was never evaluated and you passed a function into your store. You need to get the value out of it and pass *that* to redux.

This is good to know when binding a function to a component too. For example:
`<Button onPress={this.doSomething()} />`. In this case, the function `doSomething` will get evaluated when the Button is loaded, when you really want to evaluate it when it is tapped, like so: `Button onPress={this.doSomething} />`. In this case, onPress evaluates the function, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Another way to solve your problem is in the component where you render the username:

```
<Text>{review.username ? review.username : 'Anonymous'}</Text>
```

That conditionally shows username if it exists in a review object (or however it looks in your component), and shows Anonymous otherwise. This might be helpful if you need to tell whether or not the review actually has a username somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Noah, thank you for this great answer! For some reason adding the () to my action gives me an error (unexpected token). Also, for the CheckUsername function, when i pass username into it from the action is this where it is also passing the value of username to my helper file where the actual function is?

Comment: What's the error more specifically? Where's the unexpected token? I think it would be really useful for you to read up on functions, especially in javascript. And maybe a little about functional programming too. I think that would really help you to understand the problem better. Basically, in this case, check username is run whenever you call it, and it doesn't matter in what file its stored. It could be stored in the same file as your component. What matters is that when you call it, it is evaluated, and the input value to that object is replaced with the result of the evaluation.

Comment: I actually made a mistake too! You were using the default object properties to pass the username like so: `{username}`. Now just change it to `{username: username()}` or whatever the function name is now. That will make sure that the result of the function evaluation becomes the value of the object property `username`

Comment: I'm also going to edit to reflect what you mentioned earlier about the userData object being null as well

Comment: The reason your initial function won't work if userData is null is that it tries to read `username` from the property `userData`, but `userData` is null or undefined. That means that it can't read a property from it, and thus it throws the error. So you have to check for null or undefined at every level of the object hierarchy in order to guarantee the result, if you aren't sure if any of them could be null. A library called `lodash` can accomplish this easily: `const username = _.get(userData, 'username.username', 'Anonymous')`.

Comment: Perfect! The lodash solution worked like a charm. I love this library... Thanks a lot for your help and time, greatly appreciated! I do need to start separating some functions outside of my component because it does get messy... Something I'm going to have to look into more. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it worked! lodash is super useful. If this was helpful, I'll add it to my answer so you can mark it as answered ;)

Comment: I will, Please do!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create funcion for this small thing. You can write it in below fashion:

```
this.props.submitUserReview({ review, username: (this.props.userData.username.username || "Anonymous"), uid });
```

Here if value of `this.props.userData.username.username` is falsy i.e. null OR undefined OR empty string then it will pass `Anonymous` as a parameter. Hence it will solve your usecase.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried to do the following, but if I add any characters like || or () inside the dispatch, I get an error (unexpected token).

Comment: My Bad, have updated the answer! Please check, it will surely work.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! I am now recieving a new error... null is not an object (evaluating this.props.userData.username) We are passing a string, i dont see why it is complaining about an obj?

Comment: That means `this.props.userData.username.username` is not available i.e. some value in object structure is null. I was presuming that object structure exists always. In this case you can write `username: (this.props.userData && this.props.userData.username && this.props.userData.username.username) || "Anonymous"`

Comment: Okay I will try this out when I get back to my desk later on and get back to you! The object is created in firebase when the user creates their username with an input on their profile page.